# Unamos [osx] y [mac-os]

Tags: discusión, estado-completado, etiquetas, sinónimos-de-etiquetas

Tanto la etiqueta [osx](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/osx) (24 preguntas) como [mac-os](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mac-os) (103) tienen la misma descripción y se usan para lo mismo:

> macOS (antes OS X, o Mac OS X) es el sistema operativo fabricado por Apple para sus computadoras Macintosh.

Por ello, sugiero que se usan en favor de [macos](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/macos) (sin guion) por ser el nombre actual.

Opcionalmente, podría incluirse también [mac](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mac) en la unión de etiquetas. No conozco el tema con la suficiente profundidad como para poder aportar detalle, pero veo que en Stack Overflow en inglés lo tienen así.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hecho. Se ha dejado como etiqueta principal [macos](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/macos), poniendo como sinónimos [osx](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/osx), [mac-os](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mac-os) y [mac](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mac)

Comment: ¡Gracias! Además, veo que también has hecho merge a las etiquetas (por ejemplo [tag:ecmascript-2015] es sinónimo de [tag:ecmascript-6] pero no están unidas [visto en la lista de sinónimos](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms))

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar' efectivamente, lo que he hecho es un merge agregando los sinonimos, me parece mas limpio

Comment: Genial. Veo en https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms info y salen muchas etiquetas "sinónimo" con el `x N` al lado (x 88, x 269... por veces que se han usado). Creo que en estos casos quiere decir que son sinónimos pero no están unidas (merge), por lo que cuentan diferente

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar' efectivamente. Las que en la primera columna tienen el numero de usos, estan como sinónimos pero no unidas

Comment: ¿Tenéis criterio para cuándo hacer merge? Yo cuando era moderador en Spanish solía temer un poco el botón de "merge", pues es irreversible. De ahí que las dudosas las dejara sin juntar.

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar' pues...no hay un criterio hasta donde yo se. Yo tengo mi propio criterio, que es cuando pienso que nunca habrá que volver atrás (no creo que macos vuelva a llamarse osx en un futuro previsible) hago merge. En otros casos mas dudosos, no lo haria (por ejemplo, el caso de [tag:ordenacion]... que tenemos abierto, posiblemente aplicaría unicamente un sinonimo).

Comment: veo casos donde creo que ayudaría hacer _merge_ a las etiquetas, como por ejemplo [tag:boolean] y [tag:booleano]. Ahora cuando uno va a https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags aparecen diferenciadas y no es sino entrando en ellas que se ve que son sinónimas. Eso complica bastante la detección de etiquetas redundantes